# URL Rewrite Mediator WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want that whenever the user types `http://localhost:8280/services/Facebook/sea` the actual request should be `http://localhost:8280/services/Facebook/search?q=jack` . This is the part of my synapse.xml configuration for the proxy service Facebook. But its not working , whats wrong with the configuration ?

```
<proxy name="Facebook" transports="https http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
        <target>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://graph.facebook.com"/>
            </endpoint>
            <inSequence>
                <rewrite>
                    <rewriterule>
                        <action value="search?q=jack" regex="sea" type="replace" fragment="host"/>
                    </rewriterule>
                </rewrite>
                <log level="full"/>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>
    </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section which needs to be replaced is in the path of the URL. So you should set the fragment attribute to "path". The query section should be set using a separate action:

```
        <rewrite>
             <rewriterule>
                <action value="search" regex="sea" type="replace" fragment="path"/>
                <action value="q=jack" type="set" fragment="query"/>
             </rewriterule>
        </rewrite>
```